# Woocommerce login redirect if cart not empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I want to redirect the user to cart page after he logs in if the cart is not empty. I am trying this:

```
function woocommerce_custom_redirects() {

    if(!WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        wp_redirect( "https://edkasa.com/checkout" );
}
add_action('wp_login', 'woocommerce_custom_redirects');
```

But this is not working, I am using buddypress plugin, any idea where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `wp_redirect()` Function, it is suggested to follow that up with an explicit call to `exit`. For further Information on that, see [Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/).

You may thus try adding that to your Code... Something like:

```
function woocommerce_custom_redirects() {
    ob_start();     // COULD BE A GOOD IDEA
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() !== 0 || !WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        wp_redirect( "https://edkasa.com/checkout" );
        exit;       // VERY VITAL HERE TO EXPLICITLY CALL exit...
    }

}
add_action('wp_login', 'woocommerce_custom_redirects');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for and can not find anywhere as I can redirect the empty woocommerce cart to the homepage. I only find redirects that go to the store.

This is what I find, but I do not need to redirect to the home:

```
add_action("template_redirect", 'redirection_function');
function redirection_function(){
    global $woocommerce;
    if( is_cart() && WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just removed static link of previous answer.

```
function woocommerce_custom_redirects() {
 ob_start();     // COULD BE A GOOD IDEA
 if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() !== 0 || !WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
  global $woocommerce;
  $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();

    wp_redirect($checkout_url);
    exit;       // VERY VITAL HERE TO EXPLICITLY CALL exit...
 }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'woocommerce_custom_redirects');
```