# Redirect to cart page after login if the cart is not empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Wordpress 5.3.2 and Woocommerce 3.9.0, and I am trying to redirect to cart page after login.

The idea is: 
When a new user comes to the webshop, he goes to login/register and when he gets logged in it redirects him to the account page (normal behaviour). But if he already has something in his cart, when he gets logged in it should take him to the cart page, not the account page.

I already tried this solution

```
function ts_redirect_login( $redirect ) {
    $redirect_page_id = url_to_postid( $redirect );
    $checkout_page_id = wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' );

    if( $redirect_page_id == $checkout_page_id ) {
        return $redirect;
    }

    global $current_user; 
    wp_get_current_user();
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // i get that user is NOT logged in 
    } 

    return wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' );

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'ts_redirect_login' );
```

But everything I try to put in the condition part, gets me the result that I am not logged in. Also it says my cart is always empty, even if it's not.

Comment: There are possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46097939/woocommerce-login-redirect-if-cart-not-empty) ...

Comment: I tried, it's not working

Comment: Please post the version of WP and Woocommerce.

Comment: Wordpress 5.3.2 and Woocommerce 3.9.0

Comment: There's a few plugins [in the wild](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-login-redirect/) for this as well ....

Comment: yeah I tried it, but it doesn't have the possibility to add a condition to only redirect if the cart is not empty

Comment: Because the user isn't logged in until after this filter is executed.

Comment: so is there a way to put the redirect right after the filter is executed? like another filter or function?